# HowTo determine the Anchor Point of the System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext?

Tags: wpf

How to determine the **Anchor Point** of the `System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext`? exactly like **RenderTransformOrigin** in **Image WPF Control**.

```
Dim InImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("Image Path"))

Dim DrawingGroup As New DrawingGroup
Dim DrawingContext As DrawingContext = DrawingGroup.Open

DrawingContext.PushTransform(New RotateTransform(53))
DrawingContext.DrawImage(InImage, New Rect(0, 0, 500, 500))

DrawingContext.Close()
```

I want to **Render Image** using **Several Anchor Points**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean ***Anchor Point*** as the point around which the rotating is performed. So you can set that point right via the `RotateTransform`. It has a pair of properties namely `CenterX` and `CenterY`:

```
...
Dim Rotating As New RotateTransform(53)
Rotating.CenterX = Some_Value_For_X
Rotating.CenterY = Some_Value_For_Y
DrawingContext.PushTransform(Rotating)
...
```

Comment: does `CenterX` and `CenterX` are set to `DrawingContext`? i mean after i extracted Tranformed Bitmap?

Comment: @GiGatR00n of course, the `DrawingContext` is like a paper, once you draw the stuff (which can be applied with some transform), they will persist on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Complete Answer.